# Unable to sign certificate.

Tags: puppet, linux-mint

I am trying to get my hands with puppet. I boot up 2 VM both running on linuxmint 17. I intended one as puppetmaster and one as puppetclient. I am follow this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/puppet.html

in /etc/hostname
in /etc/hosts
master:
127.0.0.1 localhost /// no chance
127.0.1.1 puppetmaster //
192.168.75.141 puppetclient //this client's ip address after nm-tool search.

client:
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1  puppetclient 
192.168.75.142 puppetmaster // this is the master's ip address

In both client and master I created a file in etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

```
package {
    'apache2':
        ensure => installed
}

service {
    'apache2':
        ensure => true,
        enable => true,
        require => Package['apache2']
}
```

In master I created a file in /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp

```
  node 'meercat02.example.com' {
         include apache2
}
```

In client I create a file /etc/default/puppet and put `START=yes`. 
Here's what I think there's a problem. In the guide, the file should already exist but in my case I have to create it.

So then I followed everything in the guide to sign the client certificate. I typed in `sudo puppetca --sign puppetclient` in puppetmaster's terminal . That didn't work and I found the solution in another post. https://serverfault.com/questions/457349/installed-puppetmaster-but-why-do-i-get-puppetca-command-not-found. So after reading the post I typed `sudo puppet cert list --sign 'puppetclient'`. Then it gives me this

```
Notice: Signed certificate request for ca
Error: Could not find certificates request for list
```

After the first five pages of google search I end up here asking for help. =) Anyone can help me resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sign a certificate before there is a certificate request.

You have to establish the agent/master communication first.

#### Find out the certificate name of your master

```
puppet master --configprint certname
```

On the agent node, make sure that name resolves to the master's IP address (you currently used `puppetmaster` for this, which might suffice).

#### Send the initial request to the master

Do this on the agent node.

```
puppet agent --test --master=<name you just registered>
```

The agent generates a CSR, and prints a message that it could not receive a certificate.

#### Sign the certificate

On the master:

```
puppet cert list
```

Locate the CSR of your agent, then

```
puppet cert sign <agent>
```

The next `puppet agent --test` call will receive the certificate.

Comment: ^ thanks. I am a little confuse on what I should put puppet agent --test --master=<name you just registered>. I typed puppet agent --test --puppetmaster.localdomain. Doesn't work though.

Comment: Make that `--master=puppetmaster.localdomain`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
puppet agent --test master="name you just register"
```

its work for me.